# Is it OK to have multiple different rooms on one breaker?

Tags: electrical

My dining room, kitchen, two bathrooms, living room and den are on 1 breaker.

Should I be concerned?

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51106/is-this-too-many-items-on-a-20-amp-breaker

Comment: Do you own or are you renting?

Comment: This would not meet current National Electrical Code, however, it may have been acceptable in the past. If it's an older home, or not in a jurisdiction that has adopted NEC then it likely met code when it was built. You could upgrade the system, but you'll have to meet all current codes with the new wiring.

Answer (score 5):

You can logically have many rooms on one breaker.  It is really about what size the breaker/wire is and what it will be powering.

Given that you have a kitchen (usually 2-3 breakers minimum) and 2 bathrooms (usually on their own) plus extra I would tend to say that you have too much on it.  I doubt it would pass any current inspection.

Would I be concerned as far as safety?  Maybe.  If you are using too much your breaker should flip.  However when things are maxed out over long periods of time there are usually degradation points.  I would personally have it looked at by local inspector then  electrician.

This is really an over simplified answer but I hope it gets the point across.  What you are describing isn't normal by current standards and should be looked at.  If you give us more exacts - number of lights and outlets and breaker/wire size we can provide more science around it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about general lighting circuits for these rooms? not a problem if you have your small appliance circuits fed from this circuit call an electrician. Get a referral and try not to use fixed price franchised electrical contractors. God Bless Big Jim